# How to use functional-interface inside .kt class

Tags: lambda, kotlin, functional-interface

I would like to use some of functional-interfaces inside the `java.util.function` package like `DoubleBinaryOperator` interface.

I can use it in Java as below:

```
public enum Operation {
    PLUS("+", Double::sum),
    MINUS("-", (x, y) -> x - y),
    TIMES("*", (x, y) -> x * y),
    DIVIDE("/", (x, y) -> x / y);

    private final String symbol;
    private final DoubleBinaryOperator op;

    Operation(String symbol, DoubleBinaryOperator op) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.op = op;
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work for me in Kotlin because Kotlin cannot infer the type of the parameter.

```
enum class Operation private constructor(private val symbol: String, private val op: DoubleBinaryOperator) {
    PLUS("+", { x, y -> x + y }),
    MINUS("-", { x, y -> x - y }),
    TIMES("*", { x, y -> x * y }),
    DIVIDE("/", { x, y -> x / y });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want (SAM conversion) with the following syntax:

```
enum class Operation private constructor(private val symbol: String, private val op: DoubleBinaryOperator) {
    PLUS("+", DoubleBinaryOperator { left, right -> left + right }),
    ...
}
```

Note that this works only to implement Java interfaces, as documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions).

### EDIT

To expand on my comment below, Kotlin lambdas can be used in place of functional interfaces (what is known as SAM conversion) **only** when calling Java code from Kotlin. This is not allowed in pure Kotlin as you can use function types (e.g., `(Double, Double) -> Double`, to mimic `DoubleBinaryOperator`).

As an example, consider the following Java class:

```
public class MyClass {
    String append(String input, Supplier<String> supplier) {
        return input.concat(supplier.get());
    }
}
```

In Kotlin you can use it like this:

```
val myClass = MyClass()

// Use case 1
myClass.append("something") {
    "suffix"
}

// Use case 2
myClass.append("Something", Supplier { "suffix" })
```

Note that my IDE tells me there's a "Redundant SAM-constructor" for use case 2.

Now, let's rewrite `MyClass` in Kotlin:

```
class MyClass {
    fun append(input: String, supplier: Supplier<String>): String {
        return input + supplier.get()
    }
}
```

If we don't change the code using it, we'll get a compilation error for use case 1: "Required Supplier, found () -> String" (that's the same issue you're getting) because SAM conversion cannot be done. However, you can "force" it by using SAM constructors (that is use case 2).

Comment: Thanks, but why I need to write the interface explicitly ?

Comment: The issue is that SAM conversion (using lambdas where a functional interface is expected) only works when calling Java code from Kotlin. In your case you're defining `Operation` in Kotlin, so SAM conversion doesn't work and you need to explicitly write the type (that's called SAM constructor). The link in my answer also explains why SAM conversion doesn't work in such cases

Comment: @IbrahimAli I updated my answer adding more details, I hope it's clearer now